# Execute chaincode on a private channel, without getting access to the full state

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

we have two organisation, org1 and org2

org2 will have a private channel with chaincode on it and private state

now we want users from org1 to execute chaincode on the private channel of org2, but they can't have access to the full state (so they cannot setup a peer that can join the private channel)

how should we do this? is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure. But you can try to apply [endorsement policy](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/endorsement-policies.html). I think.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to execute chaincode on a channel one can not join. Therefore you would want to create a separate channel for org1 and org2, where org1 is the party which executes the chaincode there. If you need state information from org2, [InvokeChainCode](https://godoc.org/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim#ChaincodeStub.InvokeChaincode) provides [limited](https://lists.hyperledger.org/pipermail/hyperledger-fabric/2017-June/001168.) support for cross-channel communication.

Answer (score 0):

You have to decide which information of the org2 would be accesible for the users from org1. Then, you should define a Smart Contract according to it. The org1 and org2 will be members of the channel.

> org1 users can't have access to the full state (so they cannot setup a
>   peer that can join the private channel)

When you create a channel, you define which peers are going to be part of it. Then, the creator of the channel will control the acces to new members. So, if you create the channel, only you will be able to join new peers to the channel.

Answer (score 0):

Side DB capability which is expected in Fabric 1.1 should provide the mechanism you're looking for - ability to store some of the channel data only on a specified subset of peers (e.g. just peers that belong to org2).
https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-1151